# Cannot connect more than 4k users in Openfire installed on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, openfire

I'm running an stress test on my openfire server and I cannot connect more than 4k users.
When my computer connects 4k users, just to be sure that the problem is in the EC2, I run same test with different user offset on another computer, and still no improvement.

This is my `ulimit -a`.

```
ubuntu@amazon.ip:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31534
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31534
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

This is the end of my `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
# End of file

* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: Please, add an explicit question to avoid being closed. Some people here can't understand implicit questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I made, and it worked. 
I had to do it in both machines, the client and the Openfire one.

```
sudo su
ulimit -i 999999 
ulimit -n 999999 
ulimit -n 999999 
ulimit -p 999999 
ulimit -s 999999 
ulimit -u 999999 
ulimit -l 999999
```